# How to join the same table with multiple ids?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, left-join

My goals is to `JOIN` a table multiple times on the same `id`.

Here is a snipet of my database structure:

```
+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| wochenplan_id | wochentag_id | gericht                                 | kalorien | preis | kategorie | kategorie | inhaltsstoffe |
+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|           319 |           11 | Käse - Lauch - Suppe                    |     NULL |  2.50 | NULL      | NULL      | g,i           |
|           320 |           12 | Griechische Kartoffelpfanne             |     NULL |  2.60 | NULL      | NULL      | 10,g,i        |
|           323 |           15 | Erbseneintopf                           |     NULL |  2.60 | NULL      | NULL      | i             |
|           324 |           21 | Erbseneintopf mit Einlage               |     NULL |  2.60 | NULL      | NULL      | 1,2,11,i      |
|           325 |           22 | Erbsensuppe                             |     NULL |  2.50 | NULL      | NULL      | 1,2,11,i      |
|           326 |           23 | NULL                                    |     NULL |  NULL | NULL      | NULL      | NULL          |
+---------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+----------+-------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

```
+--------------+-------------+
| kategorie_id | kategorie   |
+--------------+-------------+
|            1 | Vegan       |
|            2 | Vegetarisch |
|            3 | Geflügel    |
|            4 | Rind        |
|            5 | Schwein     |
|            6 | Lamm        |
|            7 | Wild        |
|            8 | Fisch       |
+--------------+-------------+
```

I need to JOIN from the upper table into the `kategorien` table. I already tried some solutions here from stackoverflow but nothing is really working.

Here is my query I got so far:

```
SELECT wochenplan_id, wochentag_id, gerichte.gericht, gerichte.kalorien, preise.preis, kat1.kategorie, kat2.kategorie, gerichte.inhaltsstoffe 
FROM wochenplan 
LEFT JOIN gerichte ON wochenplan.gericht_id = gerichte.gericht_id 
LEFT JOIN preise ON gerichte.preis_id = preise.preis_id 
LEFT JOIN kategorien AS kat1 ON gerichte.kategorie_id = kat1.kategorie 
LEFT JOIN kategorien AS kat2 ON gerichte.kategorie2_id = kat2.kategorie 
WHERE wochenplan.kw_jahr = 102021;
```

I alwasy get `NULL` as a result. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: I don't understand.  What results do you want?  You show two samples of data.  Where do they come from?  Your query references four tables.  What does that have to do with the sample data.

Comment: The table "wochenplan" (first section) gets the data from other tables ("dish, calories, price, categories, ingredients"). A dish can be divided into two categories. I need a SELECT that gets the corresponding name of the category_ID and category2_ID from the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining the same table twice should work just fine.

You haven't posted the entire table structure but shouldn't you be joining the kategorien table on the Id-column?
Like this:

```
SELECT wochenplan_id, wochentag_id, gerichte.gericht, gerichte.kalorien, preise.preis, kat1.kategorie, kat2.kategorie, gerichte.inhaltsstoffe 
   FROM wochenplan 
   LEFT JOIN gerichte ON wochenplan.gericht_id = gerichte.gericht_id 
   LEFT JOIN preise ON gerichte.preis_id = preise.preis_id 
   LEFT JOIN kategorien AS kat1 ON gerichte.kategorie_id = kat1.kategorie_id 
   LEFT JOIN kategorien AS kat2 ON gerichte.kategorie2_id = kat2.kategorie_id 
   WHERE wochenplan.kw_jahr = 102021;
```